# Equal intervals between Scheduled tasks in datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-datastore

Consider I have a cron job running in app engine as below,

**every 10 minutes from 00:00 to 02:00**

My doubt is, If the task takes 5 mins to complete, Will the next task gets executed on the 15th minute or in the 10th minute?

My requirement is as below.

1. Task #1 starts at 00:00, runs for 4 mins.
2. Task #2 starts at 00:10, runs for 1 min.
3. Task #3 starts at 00:20, runs for 3 mins and so on!

Thanks,
Karthick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can find an answer in the documentation:](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Java_appengine_web_xml_The_schedule_format)

> By default, an interval schedule starts the next interval after the last job has completed. If a *from...to* clause is specified, however, the jobs are scheduled at regular intervals independent of when the last job completed. For example:

```
every 2 hours from 10:00 to 14:00
```

> This schedule runs the job three times per day at 10:00, 12:00, and 14:00, regardless of how long it takes to complete.

Comment: Thanks very much :) And Im sorry that I did not read that page so consciously. Thank you.